# Product of sum of racket lists

Tags: function, scheme, racket

I need to do a racket function to multiply 2 lists in racket in this way:

ex: l1=(1 2 3) l2=(4 5 6)
the result of the function is 189=(1+2)*(2+5)*(3+6)

I don't know where to start so please help me I'm completly lost.

Comment: please post your attempt

Answer (score 0):

You could add the first element from two lists using `car`

```
(+ (car '(1 2)) (car '(4 5)))
=> 5
```

Get the rest of the list using `cdr`:

```
(cdr '(1 2 3))
=> '(2 3)
```

```
(define product-of-sum
  (lambda (list1 list2)
    ...))
```

In the body you add the first element from both lists, then pass the rest of the list to `product-of-sum` to continue your calculation until the list is an empty list.